# How to create a value based off of the last value in a database, then increment that value by one

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have inherited a job applicant database and a webform that has a "JobID" column. In the codebehind they are getting a value from their CMS to come up with the and storing it as the "JobID". I have been asked not to use the CMS in the project I am working on and to start the "JobID" at 60,000. After the initial application, the ID should autoincrement. Using Itextsharp they then want to place that JobID on the PDF that is sent to staffing.

I know how to place the stamp the document on the PDF using Itext, I also have already created the database. I am stuck on how to start the JobID at 60,000 then have it increment afterwards. Should I alter the sqldb to have the autoincrementation start at 60,000 then, retrieve the number, and stamp it to the document? If so, How do I start the autoincrementation?

Comment: Are you forced to use an existing SQL table? Or are you making your own Job table?

Comment: I can create a new one. I know how to migrate data if I need to

Answer (score 0):

DBCC CHECKIDENT can reseed (reset) the identity value of the table. For example, YourTable has 25000 rows with 25000 as last identity. If we want next record to have identity as 60000 we need to run following T SQL script in Query Analyzer.

DBCC CHECKIDENT (yourtable, reseed, 59999)

Comment: ok so in my database I have "ID" which is the primary key being auto incremented from 1 and the "JobID" which i need to start at 60,000. How does SQL know to get "JobID" rather than "ID"?

Comment: It is not possible to place two identity columns in a single table. If there is a scope to make your ID column to GUID, then the SQL will automatically reseed your JobID. Otherwise you have to look for other options to increment manually.

Comment: Thanks, I was just doing a little research and found the same answer. I will also refer to this answer when this comes up again(and im sure it will) Thanks for your assistance. Looks like I have to find a workaround

Comment: Is it possible to instead use scope ID to grab the number of the record being inserted and add 60000 to it?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this article from Microsoft: [DBCC CHECKIDENT (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176057.aspx)

You can call DBCC CHECKIDENT to change the current identity seed on your table (i.e. 're-seed' the table). Just make sure that the new seed hasn't already been used (if you're setting to a higher value that should be okay, as long as your data type supports the range.

Use it like this:

```
DBCC CHECKIDENT('TableName', RESEED, 59999)
```

This will set the current identity seed to 59999, which means the next record (if you're using an increment of 1) will have an identity value of 60000

Comment: so how does it know the difference between the ID column and the job ID column....I understand that I can reseed the table, and how your saying I should go about it. What I do not understand is how to tell it which column to reseed

Comment: Also if ID is the primary key and its auto incrementing as Identity how is it possible to have "jobid" auto increment?

Comment: You can only have one identity column on a table; is there a separate job table you can populate and then use @@Identity after the insert to the job table to insert into this table?

Comment: Okay, so JobID is not the identity column. How about something like this:  
    CREATE TABLE dbo.Jobs (
    ID int not null identity(1,1) constraint PK_Jobs primary key clustered, 
    JobID int not null constraint UK_Jobs_JobID unique constraint DF_Jobs_JobID default (0), 
    JobName varchar(50) not null, 
    JobCreated datetime not null constraint DF_Jobs_JobCreated default (getdate())
    )
    GO
    INSERT dbo.Jobs (JobName) VALUES ('Test Job 1')
    UPDATE dbo.Jobs SET JobID = (SELECT IIF(ISNULL(MAX(JobID), 0)=0,59999,MAX(JobID)) FROM dbo.Jobs)+1 WHERE ID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
    GO